# Does acceleration of an object affect the force of gravity exerted by the object on a rope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I came across a question recently:

A 75-kg petty thief wants to escape from a third storey window. Unfortunately a makeshift rope of sheets tied together can support a mass of only 58 kg. How might the thief use this rope?

I know the answer is 2.2$m/s^2$. However, I don't understand the idea behind why the thief accelerating at this speed affects the force he exerts on the rope. Is it possible to isolate the force the thief exerts on the rope using a free body diagram and explain how his acceleration affects this force. Why does he travelling at this acceleration down the rope cause the rope to not break? Sorry if I was a little repetitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us think that the thief doesnt use the rope at all that is he just jumps off, now he is under free fall. In the INERTIAL free body diagram of the thief, the forces on him are gravity and an equal pseudo force in opposite directions while tension in rope is zero.

Now consider that the thief just holds onto the rope, without coming down, now in his FBD, gravity is balanced by the tension in the rope.

Okay, now consider the thief accelerating at say 5ms^-2 now we have a pseudo force of 75*5 newtons and some tension and gravity, now as frame is inertial,we can just take the difference of the force of gravity and our pseodo force to get tension that is obviously lower than tension in previous case.

Thus the acceleration that he decends with deciedes the tension in the rope. To get a physical intuition just think about a body accelerating with 2ms^-2 and 5ms^-2 this body would require different forces to act on it(F=ma) and as gravitation force is same, its the tension that must change to give varied accelerations.

Comment: Thank you! But as acceleration increases, tension decreases. So wouldn't the decrease in tension result in a breakage of the rope. What exactly is the tension here: the force of the rope keeping the robber from falling or the force exerted by the robber on the rope. If it's the ladder, it makes sense, since the less force exerted would result in the rope not breaking. However if its the former, than less tension means that the force of gravity would more easily overcome the force keeping the robber from falling. Is the tension force downwards or upwards?

Comment: Tension is indeed the force exerted by the robber on the rope which exerts and equal and opposite force on the robber himself. Zero tension would simply mean that rope is hanging freely. So tension on robber it upwards only.

Answer (score 1):

The thief is very well trained in physics;  he knows that saying the rope can support 58 kg is the same as saying that the rope can exert $(9.8 \times 58=568.4)$ newtons of force without breaking. (At least here on earth;  if the theft is taking place on any other planet or satellite, other calculations are needed)

So, the thief devises a clever device that allows him to slide down the rope while allowing the rope to exert the maximum possible upward force, $568.4$ N through the device, on the thief.  The thief is also aware that gravity is exerting a constant downward force or $(9.8 \times 75=735.0)$ N downward.

So when the thief steps off the window sill on the top floor of the Burj Khalifa, the only forces acting on him will be the two above, for a net downward force of $166.6$ N

It's easy to calculate the acceleration of a $75$ kg object when a net force of $166.6$ N is applied.

It's also easy to calculate that the thief will be travelling at $217$ km/hr when he hits the first floor... Oops...